# Error: Partition(s) have been written, but we have been unable to inform the kernel of the change - Ubuntu 18.04.6

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount, partition, parted

I'm running an Ubuntu VM in Azure and am unable to notify the OS of partition table changes.

```
az@prep-vm:~$ sudo parted /dev/sdb --script mklabel gpt mkpart xfspart xfs 0% 100%
az@prep-vm:~$ sudo partprobe /dev/sdb1
Error: Partition(s) 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64 on /dev/sdb1 have been written, but we have been unable to inform the kernel of the change, probably because it/they are in use.  As a result, the old partition(s) will remain in use.  You should reboot now before making further changes.
```

It also looks like the partition does not get a `UUID` assigned, only a `PARTUUID`.

- The disk is a brand new Azure managed disk
- The disk is unmounted. I've only partitioned it.

```
az@prep-vm:~$ sudo blkid
/dev/sda1: LABEL="dataDisk0" UUID="1d9c715f-b2b3-4988-8006-0e645960019b" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="4994e7f9-01"
/dev/sdc1: LABEL="cloudimg-rootfs" UUID="f89a10d0-2ae6-4411-9086-8ccd221055fd" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="b08788dd-af4a-4015-b7b0-f7b53b252ddd"
/dev/sdc15: LABEL="UEFI" UUID="C4E4-E7F8" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="12798101-40c7-4dfe-8b16-58d8522bbbc0"
/dev/sdd1: UUID="9fb76aec-c94b-4c86-9679-8445f1be4126" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="a96f9921-01"
/dev/sdb1: PARTLABEL="xfspart" PARTUUID="64f867b6-aaab-4f3f-9c7d-f8c8ebcb0752"
/dev/sdc14: PARTUUID="85d4d288-d841-4236-95ec-ca2bdb14f611"
```

I am planning on adding the partition's UUID to fstab so it's mounted on startup.

This has never been a problem before. I've tried rebooting the machine, recreating the disk from scratch + repartitioning, creating a brand new VM from a snapshot, and I keep hitting this issue. I'm a Linux newbie and have been googling/SO'ing but everything I read suggests rebooting will resolve the issue and it does not. I've also checked and there are no new versions of parted/partprobe for my distro. Not sure where else to go with it.

OS INFO:

```
az@prep-vm:~$ uname -r
5.4.0-1085-azure
az@prep-vm:~$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.6 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
```

Comment: Why would you run partprobe at all and why on /dev/sdb1 instead of /dev/sdb? Result would depend on what is on there. Which you didn't specify any where so it might as well be random data being misinterpreted somehow. And you only get UUID if there's a filesystem on there but you only made a partition, nothing else...

Comment: Following the guidance here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/add-disk?tabs=ubuntu#format-and-mount-the-disk

I edited to include more info - there's nothing on the disk. It should not be in use.

Comment: The instructions there are wrong. You don't need the partprobe at all, and if you needed it, it would be /dev/sdx and not /dev/sdx1 as the target. Partitions on partition would be weird either way...

Comment: okay, thank you